Cannot send image from react-native expo to backend FastAPI server. TypeError: Network request failed
Frontend React-Native expo:
import { router, useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

const API_URL = "http://<MY_IP_ADDRESS>:8000/analyze-image/";

const ImageScreen = () => {
  const { imageUri } = useLocalSearchParams<{ imageUri: string }>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const analyzeFood = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {

      const formData = new FormData();
      

      const filename = imageUri.split('/').pop() || 'image.jpg';
      
      console.log(filename);
      console.log(imageUri);
      

      formData.append('image', {
        uri: imageUri,
        name: filename,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
      } as any);


      const response = await fetch(API_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      

      router.push({
        pathname: "/(meal)/analyzed-food",
        params: { 
          analysisData: JSON.stringify(data)
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error analyzing food:', error);
      Alert.alert(
        "Error",
        "Failed to analyze the food image. Please try again.",
        [{ text: "OK" }]
      );
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View className="flex-1 bg-white">
      <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} className="w-full h-80" />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={analyzeFood}
        disabled={isLoading}
        className={`bg-[#159339] py-3 my-8 mx-4 rounded-full items-center ${isLoading ? 'opacity-50' : ''}`}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator color="white" />
        ) : (
          <Text className="text-white text-lg font-bold">Analyze Food</Text>
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ImageScreen;

Backend FastAPI server:
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File, HTTPException
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import requests

app = FastAPI()

API_URL = "https://vision.foodvisor.io/api/1.0/en/analysis/"
API_KEY = <MY_API_KEY>

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Adjust this in production
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.post("/analyze-image/")
async def analyze_image(image: UploadFile = File(...)):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Api-Key {API_KEY}"}
    
    try:
        # Read the image file
        image_bytes = await image.read()
        files = {"image": (image.filename, image_bytes, image.content_type)}

        # Send the image to the API
        response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, files=files)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error if the request failed

        # Parse the JSON response
        data = response.json()
        return {"data": data}

    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="An error occurred while processing the image.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

The expo app is running on my phone. The backend server is running on my PC. I am using my PC's ip address as a part of my API url. I am trying to send an image from my mobile app to the FastAPI backend server. But the API call is not happening and I am not getting anything on my backend server. It gives me TypeError: Network request failed. The error is happening on the frontend. How to solve this.

Try to change host from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

127.0.0.1 is localhost interface of your PC.This means its only accessibl from your PC and not from other devices in network (like phone)
